# Using weak_ptr.lock() to remove observers when dead

Tags: c++, observer-pattern, weak-ptr

I am currently trying to implement the Observer pattern in a little game, using [this](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/observer.html#destroying-subjects-and-observers) as reference. Though, I am trying to implement a solution to one of the problems exposed in the chapter : how to prevent the subject from sending a notification to a removed observer ?

Instead of having simple pointers or owning the observers in the subject class (with a `vector` of shared_ptrs, simple pointers, or anything that implies owning the object), I thought that it could be good to have `weak_ptr`s (knowing that the observers are already instantiated using make_shared and shared_ptr). The primary use of this to me would be to be able to check if the observer is still alive with `weak_ptr.lock()` and to remove it if it isn't, but is this a good practice ? Does this implies other problems ?

Here's my (stripped down) code :

Main method :

```
int main() {
    shared_ptr<Game> game = std::make_shared<Game>(); //Game extends subject
    shared_ptr<Renderer> renderer = std::make_shared<Renderer>(); //Renderer extends observer
    game.addObserver(renderer); //Automatic cast from shared_ptr to weak_ptr
}
```

Subject class :

```
class Subject {
public:
    virtual void removeObserverAt(int index) {
        m_observers.erase(m_observers.begin() + index);
    }
protected:
    virtual void notify(int objectID, Event ev, int64_t timestamp) {
        int i = 0;
        for(std::weak_ptr<Observer> obs : m_observers) {
            if(auto sobs = obs.lock()) {
                sobs->onNotify(objectID, shared_from_this(), ev, timestamp);
            } else {
                removeObserverAt(i);
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Observer>> m_observers;
};
```

Observer class :

```
class Observer {
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void onNotify(int objectID, std::weak_ptr<Subject> caller, Event ev) = 0;
private:
};
```

Comment: I don't follow. If you don't intend to have `shared_ptr`s, what exactly do you think `weak_ptr`s will do for you?

Comment: The goal of having `weak_ptr`s is to be able to check if the observer is dead or not, and to not own the object but simply have a reference to it (`shared_ptr` increases the reference count, right ? I'm still very new to smart pointers...)

Comment: A weak pointer can only lock an object managed by at least one live shared pointer. Yes, it doesn't own anything. But something *must* own the object.

Comment: Oh, yes - I didn't mention that my observers are already instantiated using make_shared and `shared_ptr`s - I'll edit the question

Comment: This could only work if your observers are stored as shared_ptrs somewhere outside your class. This might be usefull in some very specific case, but generally i would consider such apprach inpractical, since it makes the interface and usage very restricted.

Comment: Please do. And a small code sample to illustrate your approach will help tremendously as well.

Comment: There is an overhead to using `std::weak_ptr` so it would be more efficient for the observers to remove themselves (or for whatever deletes the observers to remove them from the observed object).

Comment: @Galik but this would mean that every Observer should keep track of the subjects they're watching, and that the Subjects should send a death notification whenever they die to tell the Observer to remove them too... I don't know if it's very efficient, but if it's the most practical solution...

Comment: It's very unlikely that all your observers need share ownership, so by using `weak_ptr` here you are adding unwanted overhead. In c++, you have destructors, take advantage of this and remove observers from observable when necessary.

Comment: Ok - so I need to have a reference to every observable I watch with an observer, to tell them to remove me from their list when I die ?

Comment: You can't change collections while iterating over it.

Comment: This doesn't look like a silly question or an insane design. Maybe not the best design evah, but not out of question. **Why is there a close request?**